# Rails5 - Ordering with Class method and params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In Rails, I want to order some tweets by number of likes desc using `params`and I am stuck..

I wrote a simple Class method in my model:

```
class Twit < ApplicationRecord

def self.most_liked
 order(like: :desc)
end

end
```

And here is my method in my controller:

```
class TwitsController < ApplicationController

 def index
  if params[:filter]
   @twits = Twit.most_liked(params[:filter])
  else
   @twits = Twit.all
  end
 end

end
```

If I only use `@twits = Twit.most_liked`, it works fine, but when I add my condition with `params` it fails.

Thank you !

Comment: This is more about fundamental knowledge of how ruby works than rails - i would recommend you start with something like http://tryruby.org to figure out the basics of the language before you start learning rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't work, because you try use never created metod. You created

> def self.most_liked
>        order(like: :desc)
>      end

But later you call 'most_liked(bla-bla)'.

You should:

- Add param to your method:

  > def self.most_liked(var1)
- Or create method:

  > def most_liked(var1)
  >   Twit.where(x=>var1).order(like: :desc)
  >   end
- Or change call of this method to:
  Model.query.method - so:

  > Twit.where(params[:filter]).most_liked

Comment: Thanks @SignorHarry !!

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you defined method self.most_liked without parameters, and then you try to pass a parameter Twit.most_liked(params[:filter]).

You should define method

```
def most_liked(some_variable)
```

or chain it with another method like this:

```
Twit.where(params[:filter]).most_liked
```

Comment: Thanks @Kamil but I still don't get it... In a nutshell, what I am trying to do is to pass a `params` in my url like this `http://example.com/twits?filter=like` and so ordering my list of tweets by the number of like. Sorry for that as I am pretty new at Rails and Ruby !